# Strange "echo" behavior in shell script

Tags: bash, echo

I want to print the content that I have obtained from the split of an array in this way:

```
string="abc test;ABCtest.it"

IFS=';' read -a array <<< "$string"
name="${array[0]}"
url="${array[1]}"

echo -ne "\n$url,$name" >> "$outputDir/$fileName"
```

But the output file doesn't contain the URL part.

I think that the problem is the `.`, but I don't know how to fix it.

If I try this

```
echo $url
```

it works!

I've tried also with `printf` and with an hardcoded filename, but nothing!

```
printf '%s %s\n' "$url" "$name"  >> test.txt
```

It seems that when I try to concatenate another thing after the variable `$url`, some part of the variable is deleted or overwritten into the output file.

For example, if I try with this:

```
printf '%s %s\n' "$url" "pp"  >> test.txt
```

What I get with a simple `cat test.txt` is this:

```
 pptest.it
```

but the content of the variable `$url` must be `ABCTest.it`.

Comment: what's the output and what do you expect?

Comment: That snippet works just fine here (without the output file). Does that *exact* snippet fail for you? Are you perhaps reading that input from a DOS-newline file in the original script?

Comment: yes I'm reading the content of a file in csv format and than I'm putting all it's content in a variable with a simple content="$(cat file.csv)" . Is this the problem ?

Comment: Consider using `printf` to improve your life.

Comment: I've tried also with printf and with an hardcoded filename but nothing!

printf '%s %s\n' "$url" "$name"  >> test.txt
It seems that when I try to concatenate another thing after the variable $url some part of the variable is deleted or rewrited into the output file

For example if I try with this

printf '%s %s\n' "$url" "pp"  >> test.txt
What I get with a simple cat test.txt is this :

 pptest.it
but the content of the variable $url must be ABCTest.it

it's very strange

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To complement [chepner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29397823/45375):

- If **output doesn't *look* what you expect it to look like**, it's always **worth *examining* its contents to look for *hidden control characters*** that may change data's appearance *on output*.
- `\r`, a CR (carriage return; ASCII value 13) is a notorious example for two reasons:

  - (As @chepner has stated) it moves the cursor to the beginning of the line mid-string, effectively erasing at least part of what came before it; e.g.:

    - `echo $'abcd\refg'` prints `efgd`: the `\r` causes everything after to restart printing at the beginning of the line, with only the `d` from the string *before* the `\r` surviving, because it *happened to be* 1 char. longer than the string that came *after*.
      (Note: The `$'...'` syntax is a so-called [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), which allows use of escape sequences such as `\r` in `$'...\r...'` to create *actual* control characters.)
  - Files with unexpected `\r` chars. occur frequently when interfacing with the Windows world, where line breaks aren't just `\n` chars., but `\r\n` sequences, and such files behave strangely in the Unix world.
- A **simple way to examine data is to pipe it to `cat -et`**, which highlights control characters as `^<char>` sequences:

  - `^M` represents a `\r` (CR)
  - `^I` represents a `\t` (tab. char)
  - `^[` represents an ESC char.
  - `... # see 'man cat'`
  - The end of a line is represented as `$`
  - Thus, a file with Windows-style line endings will show `^M$` at the end of the lines output by `cat -et`.
- `cat -et` applied to the above example yields the following, which makes it easy to diagnose the problem:

  - `echo $'abcd\refg' | cat -et  # -> 'abcd^Mefg$' - note the ^M`
- `dos2unix` is the go-to tool for **converting Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`) to Unix ones (`\r\n`)**, but this tool doesn't come preinstalled on most Unix-like platforms, and it's **easy to use standard POSIX utilities** to perform such a conversion:

  - `awk 'sub("\r$", "")+1' win.txt > unix.txt`
  - Note that this POSIX-compliant command doesn't allow you to replace the file *in-place*, however:

    - If you have *GNU* `sed`, the following would perform the conversion *in place*:

      - `sed -i 's/\r$//' winIn_UnixOut.txt`
    - Ditto with *BSD* `sed` (also used on *OSX*), from `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`:

      - `sed -i '' $'s/\r$//' winIn_UnixOut.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, the value of `$string` ends with a carriage return. What you are actually echoing is

```
echo -ne "\nABCtest.it\r,abc test"
```

That carriage return causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the current line before printing the text that follows it, overwriting the url. Either remove the carriage return with

```
string=${string#?}
```

or fix how `string` is set in the first place (I suspect you are reading from a file that uses DOS line endings, in which case you can convert the file with `dos2unix`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
echo -ne "\n""$url"",$name" >> "$outputDir/$fileName"
```

Comment: What the shell/OS do you use? What is desired output and what is your output?

Comment: bash/OS X Yosemite ver. 10.10.2

my input is a csv file with a content like this :

abc test;ABCtest.it
abc test2;ABCtest2.com
xyz test3;XYZtest3.org
etc.

Comment: This is an output of your code (without >> "$outputDir/$fileName" part) on Yosemite 10 I have: ABCtest.it,abc test